# DateTimePicker - maxDate autoselect the date

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, maxdate

When initializing my `datetimepicker` in JS with a maxDate, my input-field will autoselect the maxDate I've set. But I want to have an empty field instead. How can I do that?

```
$(".mydatepicker").datetimepicker({
      locale: "de",
      format: "L",         // only date without time
      minDate: "1900/01/02",
      maxDate: "2018/07/31"
});
```

Comment: It's not selecting the max date by default. What happens is that the maxDate is "2018/07/31" which is TODAY. It selects the current date by default. Try changing maxDate and it will still select "2018/07/31" by default

Comment: Ah, now I got it how the DateTimePicker works.. I've tried setting maxDate to 1900/01/01 too and it also selected the older date automatically. but when setting the maxDate with a future date, it works fine. thanks for info!

Comment: FYI, format: "L" will select the day in letters i.e. "Satuday, Monday, ..etc" if you want to get only full date without time use `format : "Y/m/d"` it will show it as "2018/07/31" NOTE the capital Y

Comment: "format: L" works fine for me. I'm using moment-with-locales for the formatting. It shows the german date correctly: 31.07.2018 (without time). without the formatting it shows me: 31.07.2018 11:53